# Using python BOTO with AWS SQS, getting back nonsense characters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

So, I am using python and BOTO to access my AWS SQS. I have some messages in the SQS which I can see from the AWS dashboard. However, when I try to get these messages through python, the characters that come through are just gibberish. Any idea what is going on here?

```
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("us-east-1") 
q = conn.get_queue('my-worker-queue')
print q 
#read from message queue
message = q.read(60)
print message
print message.get_body()
```

Given the code above, I get the following:

```
Queue(https://queue.amazonaws.com/247124526695/my-worker-queue)
<boto.sqs.message.Message instance at 0x16f31b8>
??e??b?+??-
```

The text in the message queue is the following:

```
hello this is a test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the reason is `base64` decoding issue, as boto uses `base64` for messages encoding and decoding. You can try to use [`get_body_encoded` method](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/ref/sqs.html#boto.sqs.message.RawMessage.get_body_encoded):

```
print message.get_body_encoded()
```

Other option is convert to [RawMessage](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/831):

```
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage
q.set_message_class(RawMessage)
```

**Update**

Yes it is, it became clear with your test case:

```
>>> print 'hello this is a test'.decode('base64')
??e??b?+??-
```

Comment: That works for that simple message, but if I switch to json format, say for example: '{"myMessage": "hello this is a test"}' using get_body_encoded() strips out {, " and :

Comment: @user602525 see for other option, from boto issue tracker. But I guess there must be other problems in your sqs interaction outside this code, with how you write it to sqs), as get_body_encoded should return raw value, as it is (byte) read from queue.

Comment: Good one! Also, get_body_encoded method link seems to be broken.

Comment: Regular messages *assume* they are base64 encoded, and apparently they just strip out non-base64 characters - which is why it removed `{,:"`. So you can either use `RawMessage` or `base64.b64encode(your_message)`.